# How does this app opens a localhost port from Browser?

Tags: javascript

I came across this app https://stackblitz.com/local and it has ability to run `NodeJS` directly on browser locally.

It  just somehow open a localhost port and I was able to interact with that localhost in another tab.

I know that `ServiceWorkers` has ability to intercept fetch requests but there is no where I can find how `ServiceWorkers` can have the ability to intercept localhost requests.

How does this works?

Comment: Could you please provide the link you get? Is it like `localhost:8080` ?

Comment: https://blog.stackblitz.com/posts/introducing-webcontainers/

Comment: but they provide a domain like `https://http-server-6yzmxi--8080.local.webcontainer.io/`. It's not actually a localhost. They route requests to their machine

Comment: You need to upload your files to their server afaik

Comment: @AmirSaleem No, it works locally. They provided me `localhost:3000`.

Comment: @AmirSaleem Of course, I found URL like this `https://http-server-6yzmxi--8080.local.webcontainer.io/` too but it actually routes to Service Worker.

Comment: What if you have another application running on your local on same port? Do they ask you to use a different port?

Comment: @jfd348 They don't use any special browser APIs in the current beta as far as I know. It just bundle a V8 like engine with Node (WASM compiled) then spawn several SWs

Comment: @AmirSaleem I didn't check that one yet

Comment: just tried one. I have an application running on localhost:8080 and stackblitz also gave me the url with port 8080 `https://http-server-ra2axm--8080.local.webcontainer.io/` So it is clearly not pointing to my local.

Comment: @AmirSaleem Did you see this on Terminal?  `ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000`

Comment: @AmirSaleem Of course, the same url doesn't works in an another browser. But it works in my browser.

Comment: If you open that URL, e.g. `http://localhost:3000` in a new browser tab (_not_ in Stack Blitz), do you actually see your app there?